# Trigger Question - Automating territories

Tags: trigger

I'm trying to create my first trigger... it should lookup a ShippingPostalCode and compare it to the Zip_Code__C field in a custom object I've created (Zip_Codes__c) and return the Area_Code__c field to a custom field on the account.

Here is what I've worked out but its not returning anything -my test class was successful. Any thoughts??

Look forward to learning!

```
trigger UpdatePrimaryArea on Account (before insert, before update) {
    //get set of Postal Codes from accounts to be inserted or updated
    Set<String> postalCodes = new Set<String>();
    for(Account a : trigger.new){
        if(a.ShippingPostalCode != null){
            postalCodes.add(a.ShippingPostalCode);
        }
    }
    if(postalCodes.size() > 0){
        //create Map of custom object records with Name (PostalCode) as key
        Map<String,Zip_Codes__c> validPostalCode = new Map<String,Zip_Codes__c>();
        for(Zip_Codes__c obj : [SELECT Id, Name, Zip_Code__c FROM Zip_Codes__c WHERE Name IN :postalCodes]){
            validPostalCode.put(obj.Name,obj);
        }
        for(Account a : trigger.new){
            if((Trigger.isInsert || trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).ShippingPostalCode != a.ShippingPostalCode) && validPostalCode.containsKey(a.ShippingPostalCode)){
                //Primary_Area__c
                a.Primary_Area__c = validPostalCode.get(a.ShippingPostalCode).Zip_Code__c;
            }
            else if(trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).ShippingPostalCode != a.ShippingPostalCode && !validPostalCode.containsKey(a.ShippingPostalCode)){
                //blank value if new PostalCode does not match a record in the Map
                a.Primary_Area__c = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A small note: Trigger.oldMap not available for insert event, you may want to rewrite that if and else condition based on that.

Comment: What doe you mean by "My Test class is successful"? Did you assert that the Correct area code was put into the correct field on the record? Since you say it is successful, posting your test class here will help to identify the differences as a truly successful test class and a unsuccessful manual test are usually due to missing a parameter in the record or something when doing the manual test.

Comment: (1) `validPostalCode` should be renamed to `postalCodeToZipCodeMap`; (2) most people would rename `obj` to something like `zc` or `zip`, (3) javanoob comment is accurate; (4) If your business case is to always have an accurate area code in Account, then all this testing for whether the postal code has changed is irrelevant - just grab what you find in the map, (5) map keys are case sensitive so if you are dealing with Canadian postal codes, then you need to make the map key lowercase and do the lookup using a lowercase key (or upper/upper)